# android setText with getString using variable name

Tags: java, android, mobile, gettext, settext

So, searching the internet I found many examples that were not what I need...

Here is my situation:

Imagine that you have a resource that is an array called songs and many 's with each song name..so, imagina you have like 200 song names displayed on a listview..

when you click a song, the app loads another activity with the lyrics for that song...
but HOW do you do that?

Here is how I did it.. I passed the name of the song to this new activity, loaded the resource where the lyrics are...

BUT, at the time I have to setText with the lyrics, I got a problem... should I do a switch with 200 cases? that sounds insane, so, what I did was, I used the same name of the song to the lyrics..so it should load like this:

```
TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String[] musicas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.botafogo_songs);
    // this here is where it brings the name of the music to the activity
    String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
    // displaying selected product name
    if (Arrays.asList(musicas).contains(product)) {
            //just formating so they have the same name.
        String productSplit = product.split("- ")[1];
        productSplit.replace(" ", "");
        txtProduct.setText(getString(R.string.AbreAlas)); 
    }else{
        txtProduct.setText("não contem");
    }
```

Ok, AbreAlas is the name of my resource..it loads fine..
BUT, I cant leave it like this...it should be a variable name...
like: `R.string.+productSplit`
or something like this..

I can't find the solution nowhere..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getIdentifier()`:

```
int resourceName = getResources().getIdentifier(productSplit, "string", getPackageName());
```

And then:

```
txtProduct.setText(getString(resourceName));
```

Don't forget to wrap that in a try and catch.

Comment: Got it to work! changed the code a lil bit...

`if (Arrays.asList(musicas).contains(product)) {
         String productSplit = product.split("- ")[1];
         //txtProduct.setText("@string/"+productSplit.replace(" ", ""));
         String productTrim = productSplit.replace(" ", "");
         int a = this.getResources().getIdentifier(productTrim, "string", getPackageName());
         txtProduct.setText(a); 
  }else{
   txtProduct.setText("não contem");
  }`