# Android : Get string for its number

Tags: java, android

I want to show sentences for its number.

Getting number with **EditText**, and sentences are in `string.xml`
Name of strings are

`sen_(number)`

**ex:** sen_1, sen_25

I tried to make the code to String, so I did like this.

`(sentence_num is getString of EditText)` `(sen_1 is "Hello, world!")`

```
    String getTxtString = "getText(R.string.sen_" + sentence_num + ")";

    TextView scrambled_sen = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scrambled_sentence);
    scrambled_sen.setText(getTxtString);
```

But it shows `getText(R.string.sen_1)`, not `"Hello, world!"`.

How can I make it show string with its number?

I want to put `getTxtString` for a java code, not a String.

Comment: what is exactly you want

Comment: Seems like you want to dynamically load string resources? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121648/android-settext-with-getstring-using-variable-name/15121736#15121736) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to get the string but a better and non-complicated way is through a **switch case** or the **if else** method.

Something like

```
If(editText value equals something){
   return getString(R.string.sen_1);
}
```

Minimizes the errors that you could cause through the first **getIdentifier()** method too.

Comment: I already thinked about that. But I have to put 800 sentences.

Comment: If my answer has answered your question, please mark it as complete.

Comment: Well, I'm really sorry but this is not what I want. I have to make almost 900 'else if' when using that. If I can't find a answer, I will check it. Thanks.